# sql getting pivoted top 5

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a sales table with the following columns:

```
[Date], [StoreID], [ItemID], [AmountInDollars]. for example:

06052012 | 1  | 111 | 2.35
06052012 | 1  | 222 | 5.00
06052012 | 2  | 333 | 9.99
...
01052012 | 30 | 999 | 3.98
```

i want to be able to select the data in this way:

```
[Date] |  [StoreID] | totalSalesForTheDay | TopSellingItemID1 | TopSellingItemID2 | TopSellingItemID3
```

I am trying the following:

```
select date,
       storeID,
       sum(AmountInDollars),
       ItemID
from sales
group by date,
       storeID,
       ItemID
```

This gives all ItemIDs sold in that day...
How can I
1. Limit to only 3 top items
2. present the 3 top items in the same lines horizontally

Thanks!

As requested - data sample. This is an original table

```
Date | StoreID | ItemID | AmountInDollars
06052012 | 1  | 111 | 2.35
06052012 | 1  | 222 | 5.00
06052012 | 1  | 444 | 9.99
06052012 | 1  | 222 | 5.00
06052012 | 1  | 444 | 9.99
06052012 | 1  | 333 | 9.99
06052012 | 1  | 444 | 9.99
06052012 | 2  | 222 | 5.00
06052012 | 2  | 444 | 9.99
06052012 | 2  | 333 | 9.99
06052012 | 2  | 444 | 9.99
05052012 | 1  | 111 | 2.35
05052012 | 1  | 222 | 5.00
05052012 | 1  | 444 | 9.99
05052012 | 1  | 222 | 5.00
05052012 | 1  | 444 | 9.99
05052012 | 1  | 333 | 9.99
05052012 | 1  | 444 | 9.99
05052012 | 2  | 222 | 5.00
05052012 | 2  | 444 | 9.99
05052012 | 2  | 333 | 9.99
05052012 | 2  | 444 | 9.99
```

will result in:

```
 Date     | StoreID |totalsales |  TopSellingItemID1 |  TopSellingItemID2 |  TopSellingItemID3 
 06052012 | 1       | 52.31 | 444 | 222 | 111
 06052012 | 2       | 34.97 | 444 | 222 | 333
 05052012 | 1       | 52.31 | 444 | 222 | 111
 05052012 | 2       | 34.97 | 444 | 222 | 111
```

Thanks...

Comment: what DBMS? sql server? mysql? oracle?

Comment: do you have the data avalable on what itemId got sold each day and in what amounts (Quantity)?

Comment: no, but i guess i can sum(ItemID) over it. I was thinking of ranking over sum(ItemID)?

Comment: Can you give a data sample of the result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Vertica supports Pivot.

Here's an answer to a similar question: [How do I do a Crosstab in Vertica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449781/how-do-i-do-a-crosstab-in-vertica)